# Reading specific column from a csv file natively

Tags: python, csv

I want to read a specific column of the `answer.csv` file named "Answer".

My code here reads the entire thing:

```
#Reading in the corpus

with open('answer.csv','r', encoding='utf8', errors ='ignore') as fin:
    raw = fin.read().lower()
```

Is there a way I can do it natively in python without using pandas?

Comment: Would it be OK to use the built-in `csv` module to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can now split at "\n" and then at ",":

```
with open('answer.csv','r', encoding='utf8', errors ='ignore') as fin:
    raw = fin.read().lower()

rows = raw.split("\n")
for i in range(len(rows)):
    rows[i] = rows[i].split(";")  # <--- your delimiter

column = []
for j in rows:
    column.append(j[1])

print(column)
```

If you want to exclude the first line, you need to start with `i = 1`.
Also you could use lambda function:

```
with open('combat.csv','r', encoding='utf8', errors ='ignore') as fin:
    raw = fin.read().lower()

rows = raw.split("\n")
rows = map(lambda x: x.split(";"), rows)
column = list(map(lambda x: x[1], rows))
```